# Как читать только новые цифры, без старых чётных/нечётных чисел в текстовый документ?

Tags: c#

Суть кода чтобы водить число, потом определить число чётное или не чётное, после определения написать число в текстовый документ, и в конце уже показать все числа из документа. В первый раз теста все нормально, но когда делаешь второй, то он показывает числа которые были в первом тесте, которые не должен, и показывает числа второго теста, что должен.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace estudo_4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num;
            char opcao = 'a';
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opção 's' = introduzir os números | 'n' = parar");
                opcao = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (opcao == 's')
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Introduza ó número:\n");
                num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (num % 2 == 0)
                {
                    StreamWriter x;
                    string par = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\par.txt";
                    x = File.AppendText(par);
                    x.Write(num);
                    x.Close();
                    }

                    if (num % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        StreamWriter z;
                        string impar = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\impar.txt";
                        z = File.AppendText(impar);
                        z.Write(num);
                        z.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
                while (opcao != 'n');

            StreamReader c;
            string lerpar = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\par.txt";
            c = File.OpenText(lerpar);
            while (c.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                string linha = c.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Os número pares:\n" + linha);
            }
            c.Close();

            StreamReader v;
            string lerimpares = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\impar.txt";
            v = File.OpenText(lerimpares);
            while (v.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                string linho = v.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Os números impares:\n" + linho);
            }
            v.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

для более удобного общения, вот мой телеграмм @danylo71

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте свой вопрос и добавьте вместо скрина с кодом - сам код в ваш вопрос.
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы делаете тест, без проверки предыдущих результатов, сначала надо проверить какие числа уже проверялись

Answer (score 0):

Используйте следующую конструкцию:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\danil\Desktop\test.txt";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
{
    writer.WriteLine("result");
}
```

Данный код перезаписывает файл по указанному пути.

```
namespace estudo_4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num;
            char opcao = 'a';
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opção 's' = introduzir os números | 'n' = parar");
                opcao = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (opcao == 's')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Introduza ó número:\n");
                    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (num % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        string par = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\par.txt";
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(par, false))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(num);
                        }
                    }

                    if (num % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        string impar = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\impar.txt";
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(impar, false))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(num);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            while (opcao != 'n');

            StreamReader c;
            string lerpar = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\par.txt";
            c = File.OpenText(lerpar);
            while (c.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                string linha = c.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Os número pares:\n" + linha);
            }
            c.Close();

            StreamReader v;
            string lerimpares = "C:\\Users\\данил\\Desktop\\impar.txt";
            v = File.OpenText(lerimpares);
            while (v.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                string linho = v.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Os números impares:\n" + linho);
            }
            v.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText`? `File.AppendAllText`? `File.ReadAllLines`?